# How can I binding different value for android:layout_marginLeft based LiveData<Boolean> in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Code B works well.

`aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord` is `LiveData<Boolean>`, I hope to set different `marginLeft` based the value of `aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord` .

Bur Code A get the following compile error, how can I fix it?

*Cannot find a setter for <android.widget.TextView android:layout_marginLeft> that accepts parameter type 'float'*

**Code A**

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/title_Date"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord? @dimen/margin1: @dimen/margin2 }"
  />

  <dimen name="margin1">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="margin2">5dp</dimen>
```

**Code B**

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title_Date"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin1"
  />

  <dimen name="margin1">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="margin2">5dp</dimen>
```

BTW, the following code can work well.

```
android:padding="@{aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? @dimen/margin1 : @dimen/margin2 }"
```

Comment: It threw an exception because `layout_marginLeft` doesn't accepts `float` value, it accepts a type of value called `dimension`. You can see that in the attr xml file. As what @Tobi have answered bellow, you can use a `BindingAdapter` to set margins programmatically. As far as I know, it is the only way to bind these margin attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this working you will have to define a custom `@BindingAdapter`:

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("marginLeftRecord")
    public static void setLeftMargin(View view, boolean hasRecord) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(
                hasRecord ? (int) view.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin1)
                          : (int) view.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin2)
                , 0, 0, 0);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Whether you need `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` or others depends on the parent of you TextView.

To use this adjust your xml to:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_Date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    marginLeftRecord="@{aHomeViewModel.isHaveRecord}" />
```

Tested and working ;)

Comment: Thanks! I have test `android:margin="@{aHomeViewModel.displayCheckBox? @dimen/margin1 : @dimen/margin2 }"` doesn't work

Comment: @HelloCW please see my updated answer. You will have to define a custom BindingAdapter. I tested it and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there other way to do that except `@BindingAdapter` ?

Comment: None that I am aware of. But @BindingAdapters are a really nice tool. You can do a lot with them that is not possible by default ;)

Comment: @HelloCW Hope that helped you. BTW, if you just need one BindingAdapter in your App, you don't need to create an extra class. You could add the method to your View or ViewModel class.